# Dynamically load an image in a Jasper Report when image path is provided from database

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, report

I want to display an Image in a JasperReport whose relative path is stored in a table in MySQL. The name of column is `photo`. I am trying this in the following way but get a blank box:

```
<image scaleImage="FillFrame" onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement uuid="aac93115-362a-4bf3-a83d-fcceba4c0922" x="413" y="79" width="141" height="160"/>
        <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
        </box>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{photo}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: Maybe if you try `onErrorType="Error"`. If the Jasper Reports' engine is not able to render the image for some reason, it should raise an exception. It could get easier to debug.

Comment: You should pass absolute image path using parameter.